# BagOfVisualWords in Accord .NET

Tags: accord.net

I'm working on image processing, and I'm trying to extract features of some images using Accord .NET framework. I have downloaded Accord.Imaging and included it in my project but still class **BagOfVisualWord** is not visible. Does anybody know why is this happening and how to solve it?

Here is my code:

```
var bow = BagOfVisualWords.Create(new Haralick() {
    CellSize = 256, // divide images in cells of 256x256 pixels
    Mode = HaralickMode.AverageWithRange,
}, new KMeans(3));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have moved from Accord.Imaging to Accord.Vision sometime after version 3.3.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps me